# Entity Framework 6 Web Forms Guide?

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, webforms

I'm working to make a legacy VB.NET web forms application a little more modern.  Rather than re-write the app in MVC, I'd rather keep the app in web forms, but overhaul the stringly typed database calls with a strongly typed Entity Framework model (or models). I can't find much information regarding Web Forms and EF6.  Is there a good guide out there to help?

Comment: This is a bit broad (not to mention resource recommendations are off-topic).  Though I imagine any EF examples and walk-throughs which don't use MVC will be just fine.  You could very easily define a handful of business models and create an EF-backed unit of work and repository similar to what I did a while back here: http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/persistence-ignorance-with-entity.html

Comment: The following guide is confusing me: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-2 I want to do all the work server side, rather than using the EntityDataSource control.  Thanks, I'll take a look at your site.

Comment: I agree, I don't much care for what that tutorial is showing.  But then I've never liked declarative data sources in page markup.  As a learning exercise, forget about WebForms entirely for a bit and see if you can get some EF samples working in just a Console Application.  No UI binding at all, just pure code access to the database.  This should help you separate the data access from the UI.

Answer (score 3):

I have some experience in dealing with legacy ASP .NET Web Forms apps and i can give you the following advices:

1) Create a new project that represents the bussiness layer, this is an interface that´s going to comunicate the presentation layer (Web forms) with the Data access Layer (Entity framework). Check [Bussiness Access Layer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581779.aspx)

2) Create a new project that represents the data access layer. Inside the project create a model of EF using Database First approach. This tutorials will help you [Entity Framework 4 and ASP .NET Web Forms](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-1) and [Entity Framework and ASP .NET Web Forms CRUD](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2015/04/how-to-implement-basic-crud-functionality-entity-framework-aspnet-webforms.html) and this one (full code with explain) [EF & Database First & Web Forms](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-Forms-97f8ee9a).

Every new method you migrate using this new aproach is going to the bussines layer so it doesnt affect the actual working project.

3) Create a new Unit Test project that tests every new method of the bussiness layer. I would suggest this tutorial [Writing Unit Tests for the .NET Framework with the Microsoft Unit Test Framework for Managed Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598960.aspx)

Keep in mind that this is approach will help you test the new and maintain the old working on!